# Wordpress returning half a response

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, lamp

Running out of ideas that could be causing this issue so just thought I would throw it out there.

I am currently developing a site based on Wordpress which has some search functionality powered by a web service. The web service returns a load of details of various residential properties, including absolute image paths which I am requesting and caching on first request.

I embedded RoyalSlider into the page to display the images in a form of gallery. This works brilliantly locally, but the issue I am seeing is when I stick the site onto a staging server. My page just fails silently whilst loading, halfway through loading my RoyalSlider thumbnails. I have checked the raw response from the server and indeed it appears that the response just stops halfway through loading all of my RoyalSlider images. But its a 200 response, no 404's, no console errors, nothing.

Oh and I should mention that if I set a break on my loop which renders my  markup, i.e limit it to say, 10 iterations, the problem does not persist and the entire page loads (albeit with only 10 of my images loaded).

Does anybody have any idea what would cause something like this to happen?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The main cause of this issue was a difference in PHP versions. This should have been one of the first things I checked, as I was seeing problems in one environment and not in another - I had just complacently assumed I was on 5.3.

The php version on my staging server (5.2) seems to have had some kind of issue with my caching layer - although what that was exactly is still unclear (leaning toward something to do with output buffering as suggested above). Updated the php version on staging though and that appears to have fixed my issue.

Thanks for the ideas Adam!